# Recursively finding average in array with only one parameter array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, average

I'm taking a class in Java and one exercise asks to find the average (double) in an array of type int recursively, the method takes a single array as parameter. 
I have been working in this for a while and haven't come out with the answer someone could lead me in the right direction?

I was able to sum all the elements together but when diving by the array's length I realized this changes every time it gets in the method in a smaller value.

Here the code so far:

```
public static double findAverage(int[] classRoom) {         
      if(classRoom.length > 0) {
          int grade = classRoom[0];
          int[] newArray = new int[classRoom.length-1]; //create newArray with array length -1
          System.arraycopy(classRoom, 1, newArray, 0, newArray.length); //copy array into array length -1
          return  grade + findAverage(newArray);
      }
      else
         return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note, creating 9999 arrays to calculate the average of an array with 10000 elements is quite ugly. This would only make sense as an academic challenge.

Comment: Knowing the length of an array and the average of its elements' values, you can compute the sum of the values (within floating-point computational error) by multiplication.  With that information, you can compute the average of the elements of an array obtained by pre- or appending one additional element of known value.  In this way, you can use known information and the return value of a recursive call to compute the appropriate return value for your function.

Comment: Are you permitted to create a private helper method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
public static double findAverage(int[] classRoom) {
    if (classRoom.length == 0)
        return 0;

    int grade = classRoom[0];

    if (classRoom.length == 1)
        return grade;

    int[] newArray = new int[classRoom.length-1]; //create newArray with array length -1
    System.arraycopy(classRoom, 1, newArray, 0, newArray.length);//copy array into array length -1 
    return  (grade + findAverage(newArray) * newArray.length) / classRoom.length;
}
```

In that last line, you are doing `average * length` to get the sum, so you can then sum your current value and then divide by the overall length (which is of course `newArray.length + 1`.

Again, this would not make sense at all in a real-world scenario, but just as an academic challenge.

As a final note, "find" usually refers to finding an element in the array. In this case, you are not finding anything but rather calculating the average, so the function name doesn't seem right to me either.

Comment: Always do as your professor wants. But try to learn the proper way for the rest of your life. :)

Comment: Btw, on other topic I'm handling exceptions for this exercises as well and runs fine until I enter an invalid number (to try) after re-running the program, this is after the first run when asking to re-run with different values if I happen to enter invalid values it won't throw the exception and I don't know why? 

It's something I don't know or is it my code?

Thanks

Comment: Well, if it solved your question, you should mark this answer as accepted, so your question does not remain unsolved. Regarding your issue, I don't see where you insert a number, here you just send an array. Are you talking about entering integers with the keyboard? That sounds like a completely different matter, related to parsing string inputs as integers, and there is plenty of information about that on the web. [This is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+input+parseint), but feel free to create another question if you feel no other existing answer here is of use for you.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new using the platform and I am still getting familiar. So didnt submit that part of the code but I'm initializing the array with grades that the user enter from keyboard of integer type. I submitted the same question with a similar exercise where you can see it.